# get data from firebase document with "where" query without specific doc()

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Im trying to look for a document where value "phone" is equal to the phone number that was input by the user

ive tried:

```
async getUserIdOfPhoneNumber(phone){
 

  this.afs.collection("users", ref => ref.where("phone", "==",phone)).doc().get().toPromise().then(() => {
  console.log(res.data())
  })
```

but that brings back undefined because im not providing an id in doc(), I dont want to provide an id because i dont know the id of the collection where the phone number the user entered is equal to the phone value in said doc

removing the doc() function just brings a different mess. data() then doesnt exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query, there are potentially multiple results. Even when you know there's only one result, the API doesn't know about this, so it returns a list. Your application code will have to deal with this list.

Since I don't see a need to use AngularFire here, this is how you can get a query result in the regular JavaScript SDK (v8 syntax):

```
firebase.firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .where("phone", "==",phone)
  .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
    });
  })
```

---

Since you know there's at most one result, you can also do:

```
  ...
  .get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
      console.log(querySnapshot.docs[0].id, querySnapshot.docs[0].data());
    });
  })
```

---

If you need to do this with AngularFire (i.e. if you want to display the document in the UI), you can use `first()` to get the first item from the observable. For more on this, see: https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+observable+get+first+value